Paginating data from DynamoDB when FilterExpression and Limit is involved
I need to paginate the data from a DynamoDB table. I have an application with Next and Previous buttons. Users should be able to navigate to the next and previous pages by clicking the respective buttons.
This is the code I've written for the same:

def paginate_dynamodb_items(table_obj, index, key, page_limit=10, **kwargs):
    """
    function to paginate dynamodb items
    """
    kwargs['scan_index_forward'] = True \
        if kwargs['pagination_direction'] == 'reverse' else False
    paginated_response = {
        kwargs['item_type']: [],
        "next_token": None,
        "transition_token": None
    }
    query_response = query_items(
        table_obj,
        index,
        key,
        return_whole_item=True,
        limit=page_limit,
        **{**kwargs}
    )
    data_res = query_response['Items']
    last_evaluated_key = query_response.get('LastEvaluatedKey')
    while last_evaluated_key and len(data_res) <= page_limit:
        query_response = query_items(
            table_obj,
            index,
            key,
            return_whole_item=True,
            limit=page_limit,
            **{
                **kwargs,
                "last_evaluated_key": last_evaluated_key
            }
        )
        data_res.extend(query_response["Items"])
        last_evaluated_key = query_response.get('LastEvaluatedKey')
    if len(data_res) > page_limit:
        data_res = data_res[:page_limit]
        if not last_evaluated_key:
            last_evaluated_key = True
    items_in_page = data_res[:page_limit]
    if not items_in_page:
        return paginated_response
    # generate next page token
    next_page_token = encode_string(
        json.dumps(
            generate_last_evaluated_key(items_in_page[-1], index)
        )
    ) if last_evaluated_key else None
    # generate transition token
    transition_token = None if not kwargs.get('last_evaluated_key') else \
        encode_string(
            json.dumps(
                generate_last_evaluated_key(items_in_page[0], index)
            )
    )
    display_items = sorted(items_in_page, key=itemgetter('time'), reverse=True)
    paginated_response = {
        kwargs['item_type']: display_items,
        "next_token": next_page_token,
        "transition_token": transition_token
    }
    return paginated_response


In the above function, query_items(), generate_last_evaluated_key(), etc. are custom functions that serve their purpose.
The Previous button and Next buttons would be disabled for the starting and ending pages respectively as transition_token and next_token will be null in those scenarios. The next_token and transition_token are pagination tokens I generate from the above function.
By sending the transition_token as the ExclusiveStartKey along with ScanIndexForward as False, I would be able to fetch the previous page, and then sort it based on the time attribute so that the sorting order is consistent in all pages.
However, if a FilterExpression is involved with the Limit parameter, it results in several looped queries, thus significantly increasing the execution time.
How do I optimize this function for lower latency and efficient querying, so that I still retain the response structure - using next_token and transition_token, but FilterExpression can also be incorporated?
Thanks in advance!

As from https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/table/query.html# official docs, limit is a parameter used to limit the maximum number of items to evaluate (for cost/efficiency reasons) meaning it wont be influenced by the count of conditional matching items based on the filter
You can see here https://github.com/pynamodb/PynamoDB/issues/681 the same problem with implications of limit vs efficiency

I get it Ariel, but how to efficiently implement a pagination strategy that fetches say, 10 items each when the "Next" and "Previous" buttons are clicked?

It depends on the parameters in the query, as far as you dont know how many matching items you are gonna get on a single query

I have implemented a design inspired from the Exponential Backoff Algorithm to iteratively increase the Limit (exponentially, although capping at a threshold value) while querying for the data using FilterExpression and Limit, significantly decreasing the paginated data's overall loading time.

The fact that you use a FilterExpression suggests that you've a sub-par data model. Creating a different data model which incorporates your Filters into the table or index keys would prevent the need for filter after read, meaning you will get the exact amount of data you requested in your Limit.

The application incorporates multiple filters in the data table. Thus, even if I scope the partition using the KeyConditionExpression, FilterExpression would be required in difference use cases within the application.

Got it. Based on the fact you have multiple filter conditions, is there a reason why you choose DynamoDB? Do you have large throughput requirements?

Yes, the scalability, large throughput, and cost efficiency that DynamoDB offers are a requirement

What's your peak RPS?

Estimated RPS is around 10,000. Changing the choice of DynamoDB at this phase is a non-feasible one.

Which is more feasible, getting your desired pagination effect or changing your database?

Well, so should it be inferred that this issue lies inherently with DynamoDB's support for displaying paginated data with multiple FilterExpressions and that the code I've shared couldn't be modified somehow to allow that?

What I typically suggest is setting your limit higher than it needs to be. And then keep track of your start and end item to use as ESK.

Thanks, Leeroy. I had already done that, even though I know it's not a scalable solution since the initial query might still return less data after filtering
